# Why wrong path annotation doesn't crash REST API with Jersey?

Tags: java, rest, tomcat, jersey

I have a running RESTful API fully working with everything ok. I'm using a HTML with JS to access my REST methods with Jersey and Tomcat7 to host it. This is the code:

```
package pact;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.ws.rs.Consumes;
import javax.ws.rs.GET;
import javax.ws.rs.POST;
import javax.ws.rs.Path;
import javax.ws.rs.Produces;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import com.google.gson.Gson;

import repo.Pessoa;
import repo.Repo;

@Path("/")
public class Rest {

Gson gson = new Gson();

@POST
@Path("escreve")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void escreve(String dado) throws IOException {
    Pessoa pessoa = gson.fromJson(dado, Pessoa.class);
    Repo.escreve(pessoa);       
}

@GET
@Path("le")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String le() {
    List<Pessoa> list = Repo.le();
    String json = gson.toJson(list);
    return json;
}

@POST
@Path("loja")
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public void loja(String dado){
    Repo.seleciona(gson.fromJson(dado, Pessoa.class));
}

@GET
@Path("lojale")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public String lojale() {
    return gson.toJson(Repo.retorna());
}
```

}

The problem is, if I change my `web.xml` at `<url-pattern>/rest/*</url-pattern>` to something like `<url-pattern>/reste/*</url-pattern>` Tomcat's description automatically changes to "Restart" and after restarting, all routes are changed to access my REST methods. Why I change `@Path("/")` to something like `@Path("/pessoa/*")` nothing happens, even saving all project, deleting Tomcat, creating another Server and publishing on it. Does this line matters? I've saw it in a tutorial and never changed. Does Jersey uses something like this?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set  **@Path("/pessoa/")** instead of **@Path("/pessoa/*")** . I think you do not need the * as only */pessoa/* itself will match both */pessoa* and */pessoa/something*

Comment: the issue is, even doing that wrong nothing really happened and my old route worked fine. My question is why this awkward behavior is happening?

Comment: Don't really know. However, worth to try with a correct Path annotation. Maybe it is ignoring it as it was wrong. Try to change for example **@Path("escreve")**, is tomcat registering the end point correctly?